# What is the infinitesimal character of the trivial representation?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Can one speak of the infinitesimal character
$\lambda \in \mathfrak{a}_\mathbb{C}^* \backslash W$ or equivalently of as $\chi_\lambda$. And if so, what is it?
Is the character just the constant 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: the additive trivial character is identically $0$, and the multiplicative trivial character is identically $1$.